# Display JS charts in Div using jQuery.AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, graph

Hi I am trying to display javascript charts in DIV tag. I want to call a url using jQuery.ajax. Following is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="./jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#btnRun" ).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/guide/start.html",
            success: function(response) {
                $('#divResult').html(response); // Assign the values to the DIV
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Run" id="btnRun" /> </br>
<div id="divResult"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to call url. But not able to display content existing in that url. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to get exactly this url (http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/guide/start.html)?

Comment: Isn't it cross domain ajax request? Do you understand what response should be comming from that url?

Comment: What is the response you are getting? HTML or JSON or XML

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery ajax cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: @Jai this is my thought too

Comment: @selite Yes. I am trying to call this page exactly. Actually I suppose to load JS graphs which looks similar to it. For that reason I have selected this url. When I call tabular format report, I am able to display in DIV tag. If I call JS reports, it is not working.

Comment: @Deva please refer to the comment of Jai about cross domain ajax request

Comment: @selite I understood it. But when I try to call local webserver links, I am not able to get graph. I am sure that I didn't call any cross domain. calling page and called page both resides in same webserver and in same location.

Comment: @Deva do you get any error/notice in your browser console. Have you tried logging the answer of the request by `console.log(response)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for my problem. I added OBJECT tag in DIV. Here is code.

```
$( "#btnRun" ).click(function() {
        $('#divResult').html('<object data="http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/guide/start.html" />');
    });
```

Thanks for All.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple of problems here:

- You're probably not allowed to do this because of Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
- You can't load more JavaScript into a page asynchronous trough another HTML-file.